# How to Make Flash Builder Package Explorer emulate Flex Builder's Navigator window?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flexbuilder

Does anyone know if there is a way to make the new Package Explorer window in Flash Builder emulate Flex Builders 'Flex navigator' window?

Bottom line is I don't always need to peer into SWC's, and I don't like having a 'default package' automatically created for me. Not sure why the interface wasn't made simpler, allowing access to more power and complexity only if necessary. I want to focus on the code, not on how to navigate and use the bells and whistles in the coding environment.

Answer (score 1):

The original "Navigator" view is still available. From the FB menu choose "Window" -> "Other views..." Open up the the "General" tree and select "Navigator" This might put the Navigator window as a tab in the bottom panel (that's where it showed up for me). You can then drag and drop the tab to place it right next to the Package Explorer. Then you can easily switch back and forth between both views.